# c# dynamic loading of file lines

Tags: c#, file, io

I'm having trouble thinking up a good way to implement a file importing class,

I'd like it to be able to read any file, then based on the delimiters of the line's content, determine the structure of the file (not the type structure),

for instance, say i had a file called, A.txt

the file contains lines of data seperated by the , delimiter,

the result would be an array of strings if i were to split by ',' however, how can i dynamically determine the delimiter, then set the output as column names?

say if the first line of a.txt was "1,2,3,4,5"

the output should be

```
delimter : ","
column[0] = "1"
column[1] = "2"
column[2] = "3"
column[4] = "4"
column[5] = "5"
```

Does anyone have any good ideas? and i'm not sure, but would it be possible to somehow magically determine what the data types can be depending on the the values of the strings are, if not this is alright, but i thought id ask anyways.

thanks

Comment: I bealive you can solve this problem with reading file as database. Please check the link below http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile

Comment: You need to be clearer about whether your concern is how to work out what the delimeters are, or how to work out what the types of the column data are.  Which is it?  There's no point hoping for 'magic' - you're even less likely to find that on a computer than you are elsewhere.

Comment: I think you are going to need to be more clear on the details.. Does it have to be perfect accuracy? Even a human might fail this test depending on the input

Comment: It does not need to be accurate, But I'd need to make my solution at least get the delimiter right. I can the front end use specify the data types so disregard my "magic" comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this.

```
 public DataTable GetDataTableFromTextFile(string filepath) 
    {
                                string line;
                                DataTable dt = new DataTable();                         
                                using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText(filepath))
                                {
                                    while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                    {
                                        string[] items = line.Split('\t',":",";","=");
                                        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                                        {
                                            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FirstColumn", typeof(string)));
                                            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SecondColumn", typeof(string)));
                                            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ThridColumn", typeof(string)));

                                        }

                                        if (items.Length > 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(items[0].ToString()))
                                        {
                                            dt.Rows.Add(items);                                       
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
    return dt;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array of symbols, which may be delimeters and a second array of symbols, which may not be delimeters, then all is easy. Just find first symbol from delimetersArray and then use it to split.

If the parts between delimeters have an equal lenghts, then that's easy too.

If the parts and delimeters may be any, there are no way to distinguish one from another.

Answer (score 1):

In case you you know the datatypes and the delimter is a single character to determine the delimiter character you can do the following (pseudocode):

```
char FindDelimiter(string firstLine)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < firstLine.Length; i++)
    {
        if(!CanBeParsedAsKnownDataType(firstLine.SubString(0,i))
        {
            // this one cannot be parsed as a known datatype anymore
            // so it must be the delimiter 
            return firstLine[i];
        }
    }

    // if we reach this, nothing was found
    return '';
}
```

Note that this only works for datatypes like numbers where a substring of the actual value can still be parsed as a datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Their is no magic available. All you can do is iterate over the first line and find out which character occurs most often. Then compare this list with a list of possible delimeter candidates and find out which one occurs first.

Here is a code example that returns a string with some analysis of the string. Maybe this is a starting point for your "magic code":

```
var line = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
var analysis = line.GroupBy(c => c);
var results = analysis.OrderByDescending(group => group.Count())
                      .ThenBy(group => group.Key)
                      .Select(group => "The character \""
                                       + group.Key
                                       + "\" appears "
                                       + group.Count()
                                       + " time"
                                       + (group.Skip(1).Any() ? "s" : String.Empty)
                                       + ".");
```